# How to recall statements in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method `calculate(some params)` having `if-elseif-else` conditions. For each condition I have some statements common to the others. I dont want to rewrite those lines. Is there any way to recall these lines like making a method of those lines within the `calculate` method?

```
  calculate(some params){

        if(condition1){
            specific tast 1 ; 
            specific tast 2 ; 
            common task ; 
        }else if(condtion2){
            specific tast 3 ; 
            specific tast 4 ; 
            common task ; 
        }else if(condition3){
            specific tast 5 ; 
            specific tast 6 ; 
        }else{
           specific tast 7 ; 
           specific tast 8 ; 
           common task ; 
        }

     }
```

**NOTE : Common task is not for every block.**

Comment: if all statements are common then why you need if-elseif-else?? suppose some common code is there you can put the same in other method and call it by your calculate()

Comment: I said  , i have some statements...not all

Comment: It might be easier to help if we saw the entire block of code.

Comment: @Aleena, you need to provide more context here. How about you write a simplified example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: i think you need solution in terms of recursion for calculate? but for that we need your solution!!!!

Comment: Let me explain myself with example...thnx @aioobe

Answer (score 2):

Just pull your `common task ;` down like this:

```
  calculate(some params){
        boolean doCommonTask = true;
        if(condition1){
            specific tast 1 ; 
            specific tast 2 ; 
        }else if(condtion2){
            specific tast 3 ; 
            specific tast 4 ; 
        }else if(condition3){
            specific tast 5 ; 
            specific tast 6 ; 
            doCommonTask = false; // Skip common task
        }else{
           specific tast 1 ; 
           specific tast 2 ; 
        }
        if (doCommonTask) {
            common task ; 
        }

     }
```

Comment: Ok, and how about this?

Comment: Yupp..that might be helpful...Thnx

Answer (score 0):

In Java there is no possibility to declared local sub-scoped method within a method (unless you do some nasty trick with a inner class).

The closest you can get is to declare a private method on the same class with those commont statements.

Alternatively if it is just a few statements and include them in the original method does not make it too large (thus less readable) then you can simply put them either before the if-else-if ... -else block or after it these can be grouped at the beginning or the end of all blocks.